# "Overall Code Coverage" not always updating

Tags: developer-console

When I run my test from "Setup | Apex Test Execution", the percentage number in the box in the lower right corner of Developer Console is correct and I can view the lines of code that were not accessed.  When I run the same test from the Developer Console, the percentage is zero and the lines of code accessed are not shown.  How can I get the Developer Console version of the test to update the percentages correctly.

The database in question is a sandbox database.

Comment: This is just weird behavior from Developer Console. My suggestiong would be close and start the console again.

Comment: tried restarting console and even rebooting computer - no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. After winter 16 release nearly 72 members reported this in success community.

Currently this issue under review. You can vote for this issue in success community.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoyAAE

Hope salesforce will fix this issue soon.